# Flag for training and test for custom layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to create a custom keras layer which does something during training and something else for validation or testing.

```py
from tensorflow import keras
K = keras.backend
from keras.layers import Layer
import tensorflow as tf

class MyCustomLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, ratio=0.5, **kwargs):
        self.ratio = ratio
        super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x, is_training=None):

        is_training = K.learning_phase()
        tf.print("training: ", is_training)
        if is_training is 1 or is_training is True:

            xs = x * 4
            return xs
        else:
            xs = x*0
            return xs

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=input_dim))
model.add(MyCustomLayer(0.5))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.05, epochs=5)
```

In the output I always get:

```
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
training:  0
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues and misconceptions here. First you are mixing imports between `keras` and `tf.keras` imports, you should use only one of them. Second the parameter for `call` is called `training`, not `is_training`.

I think the issue is that `tf.print` does not really print the value of the `training` variable as its a tensorflow symbolic variable and might change value indirectly. There are other ways to check if the layer behaves differently during inference and training, for example:

```
class MyCustomLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, ratio=0.5, **kwargs):
    super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def call(self, inputs, training=None):

    train_x = inputs * 4
    test_x = inputs * 0

    return K.in_train_phase(train_x,
                            test_x,
                            training=training)
```

Using then this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=10))
model.add(MyCustomLayer(0.5))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

And making an instance of a function that explictly receives the `K.learning_phase()` variable:

```
fun = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], [model.output])
```

If you call it with `Klearning_phase()` set to 1 or 0 you do see different outputs:

```
d = np.random.random(size=(2,10))
print(fun([d, 1]))
print(fun([d, 0]))
```

Result:

```
[array([[4.1759257], [3.9988194]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[0.], [0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

And this indicates that the layer has differen behavior during training and inference/testing.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the print works quite fine now. Just needed to make sure everything was ```tf.keras```.

Comment: @bettercallsomeone I tried with keras and tf.print and it didn't really work.

Comment: did you make sure it was `tf.keras` and not `keras`?

Answer (score 0):

So, I just figured out what was going wrong. I was mixing two different types of classes:

```py
from keras import Sequential
from tensorflow import keras
K = keras.backend
```

So, the model is using `keras` and I was calling the flag from `tensorflow.keras`. For this reason `K.learning_phase()` was not working as expected.

To fix it I used

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow import keras
K = keras.backend
```