# Change training and testing behavior of custom Layer Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to change my Keras model's behavior during training and testing.

To be more precise, I want to simply evaluate the predictions during training, and add another Lambda layer (as a kind of postprocessing) for testing.

I've found a solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427897/flag-for-training-and-test-for-custom-layer-in-keras), where `K.function`receives the specified `K.learning_phase()` and returns an output. As I understand, using `K.in_test_phase()` or `K.in_training_phase()` will return either the first or the second parameter ([as described in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/in_test_phase)), based on the training parameter passed.

I'm running on TF 2.0 as Backend, so eager execution is enabled by default. That being said, 
passing `K.learning_phase()` results in an error, which has been described see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34201#issuecomment-577596280). Hence, I'm using 
`tensorflow.python.keras.symbolic_learning_phase()`, which seems to work.
I'm currently able to get the output with `K.function()`, but my aim is to perform `model.fit()` in order to train my model,  and later call `model.evaluate()` (I'm using the Keras' functional API).

How would the proper way to train and test my model, based on the learning flag be?

Currently my MWE is:

```
def build_model(images, training=None):

    input_layer = Input(shape=(256,256,3), dtype="float32", batch_size=80)

    ...
    #performing some factor disentanglement here


    angle_pred = UpSampling2D(size=(8, 8), interpolation='bilinear')(angle)
    radius_pred = UpSampling2D(size=(8, 8), interpolation='bilinear')(radius)

    angle_radius_stack = tf.stack([angle_pred, radius_pred], 0)
    hough_voting = Lambda(hough_vote)((angle_radius_stack, images))
    train_test = K.in_test_phase(hough_voting, angle_radius_stack, training = training)

    angle_v, radius_v = tf.unstack(train_test)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[angle_v, radius_v])
    adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True) 
    return model
```

And then using training:

```
def train_model(model, patches, radii, angles):

    fun = K.function([model.layers[0].input, B.symbolic_learning_phase()], [model.layers[-1].output])
    print(fun([patches[0:80,:,:,:], True]))

    model.fit(patches, [radii, angles], batch_size=80, epochs=1)
```